# Component configuration file in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks, custom-component

Lets say i want to develop an RSS Reader reusable component for iOS with a configuration file which can me updated by user. So my wish list is as follow:

1. Add the component to a new project in single click. Just like adding framework.
2. I also want that my source files are NOT visible to other user (developer).
3. And yes if there are resources associated with it should also seamlessly be added to new project.
4. And most importantly I want the developer to be able to adjust few parameters for my component eg specifying the URL for my RSS Reader.

In short after i am done all i want the developer to see are my header files and configuration file. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a fake framework as described [here](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework).